# Android Trigger button in other xml file

Tags: android, xml, button, buttonclick

I am trying to access a button from another xml file which is used for customizing each row in my list. But how can I do this as I am getting a nullpointer exception while setting the onClick listener. My code is shown below.

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/List"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/list_item">

<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/list_item_text_view"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_marginLeft="35dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

this my activity class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

So basically how to set a onclicklistener to a b1 of row.xml while the activity view is set on main.xml

Comment: I just put a working sample o Expandable layout, just update your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

**Use LayoutInflater:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello, null);
        Button bt1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btLog);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** **EXPANDABLE LAYOUT**

```
public class ExpandablePanel extends LinearLayout {

    private final int mHandleId;
    private final int mContentId;

    private View mHandle;
    private View mContent;

    private boolean mExpanded = false;
    private int mCollapsedHeight = 0;
    private int mContentHeight = 0;
    private int mAnimationDuration = 0;

    private OnExpandListener mListener;

    public ExpandablePanel(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExpandablePanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mListener = new DefaultOnExpandListener();



        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandablePanel, 0, 0);


        // How high the content should be in "collapsed" state
        mCollapsedHeight = (int) a.getDimension(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_collapsedHeight, 0.0f);

        // How long the animation should take
        mAnimationDuration = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_animationDuration, 500);

        int handleId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_handle, 0);
        if (handleId == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The handle attribute is required and must refer "
                    + "to a valid child.");
        }

        int contentId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandablePanel_content, 0);
        if (contentId == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The content attribute is required and must refer to a valid child.");
        }

        mHandleId = handleId;
        mContentId = contentId;

        a.recycle();
    }

    public void setOnExpandListener(OnExpandListener listener) {
        mListener = listener; 
    }

    public void setCollapsedHeight( int collapsedHeight ) { mCollapsedHeight = collapsedHeight; android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams(); lp.height = mCollapsedHeight; mContent.setLayoutParams( lp ); }

    public void setAnimationDuration(int animationDuration) {
        mAnimationDuration = animationDuration;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        mHandle = findViewById(mHandleId);
        if (mHandle == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The handle attribute is must refer to an"
                    + " existing child.");
        }

        mContent = findViewById(mContentId);
        if (mContent == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "The content attribute must refer to an"
                    + " existing child.");
        }

        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = mCollapsedHeight;
        mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);

        mHandle.setOnClickListener(new PanelToggler());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // First, measure how high content wants to be
        mContent.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        mContentHeight = mContent.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (mContentHeight < mCollapsedHeight) {
            mHandle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mHandle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Then let the usual thing happen
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    private class PanelToggler implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation a;
            if (mExpanded) {
                a = new ExpandAnimation(mContentHeight, mCollapsedHeight);
                mListener.onCollapse(mHandle, mContent);
            } else {
                a = new ExpandAnimation(mCollapsedHeight, mContentHeight);
                mListener.onExpand(mHandle, mContent);
            }
            a.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
            if(mContent.getLayoutParams().height == 0) //Need to do this or else the animation will not play if the height is 0
            {
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = 1;
                mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mContent.requestLayout();
            }
            mContent.startAnimation(a);
            mExpanded = !mExpanded;
        }
    }

    private class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
        private final int mStartHeight;
        private final int mDeltaHeight;

        public ExpandAnimation(int startHeight, int endHeight) {
            mStartHeight = startHeight;
            mDeltaHeight = endHeight - startHeight;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mContent.getLayoutParams();
            lp.height = (int) (mStartHeight + mDeltaHeight * interpolatedTime);
            mContent.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public interface OnExpandListener {
        public void onExpand(View handle, View content); 
        public void onCollapse(View handle, View content);
    }

    private class DefaultOnExpandListener implements OnExpandListener {
        public void onCollapse(View handle, View content) {}
        public void onExpand(View handle, View content) {}
    }
}
```

**Layout:**
Put this on top: xmlns:cl="http://schemas.android.com/res/com.example.androidapp.widgets"
The Eclipse will always indicate an error in this layout because the Throw Exceptions in the ExpandablePanel.class, So you can hide these lines to see how the expandable layout appears and set up his button and text child.

```
<com.example.androidapp.widgets.ExpandablePanel
        android:id="@+id/theId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:collapsedHeight="80dp"
        app:content="@+id/value"
        app:handle="@+id/expand"
        cl:collapsedHeight="50dip"
        cl:content="@+id/value"
        cl:handle="@+id/expand" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/value"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hejahdkashfa afsjkhas lf ksajfh as fkjsah asf kfsahkjfas  klfajsh flkas  klfajsh lasfkl aklfsjh klsa ffhaskljfha dfasfa s safjsfkhasjkf fjakshfjkasf  jksfhjkasf sjakfhas kjfa sjkfhakjsfh asjsfhkjashf askjsf sakjfh as fadsfasf af asf asf" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/expand"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="More" />

    </com.example.androidapp.widgets.ExpandablePanel>
```

**How to set Expandable panel:**

```
// Set expandable panel listener
        ExpandablePanel panel = (ExpandablePanel)findViewById(R.id.theId);
        panel.setCollapsedHeight(50);
        panel.setContentDescription(descricao);
        panel.setOnExpandListener(new ExpandablePanel.OnExpandListener() {
            public void onCollapse(View handle, View content) {
                Button btn = (Button)handle;
                btn.setText("More");
            }
            public void onExpand(View handle, View content) {
                Button btn = (Button)handle;
                btn.setText("Less");
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Marcharaujo Thanks for replying. The exception is gone but nothing happens whn I click the button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't from there.  That secondary xml file isn't inflated or set as the context view, so the button doesn't exist.

What you can do is in the list's adapter in the getView function you'll inflate that row view (probably several times for different rows).  Once you inflate it you'll get a View class for the top level view in the row xml, then you can run findViewByID on that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I need to start an intent after the click and it is not possible in the adapterclass :(

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom Listview?

Comment: Yes custom expandablelistview  and each listItem has a button. I am trying to access tht button

Comment: You can start an activity in the adapter.  Just make a custom adapter and pass in the activity as a parameter in the constructor, then you can call startActivity on the passed in activity.  Or make it an inner class of the activity and call the function directly.